# Waiting for webpack bundling before launching nodemon

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have a nodejs project written in Typescript. Therefore, i have webpack using a typescript loader that transpiles my code in Javascript and bundles it in a server.js file (in a dist folder)

When in developement conditions, my webpack runs with its watcher ON and so does nodemon.

Problem is, when i launch my script for the first time combining webpack and nodemon, since webpack is in watch mode it doesn't have an exit code saying that everything is ok, nodemon script can be started. If i run them simultaneously, nodemon will launch faster than webpack and since server.js file doesn't yet exist, it will crash at the start.

I want to launch thanks to one single command both scripts but make nodemon command wait for the bundling to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when please provide some code when submitting questions.

`and since server.js file doesn't yet exist`

I think you should work around your setup a little bit s.t. webpack doesn't create your server.js file if you want to do this.

Basically you can chain multiple commands in a script like so `webpack -d && nodemon index.js`. This will launch node after webpack completes. **However** if you setup webpack in watch mode `-w` it never exists, so you can't chain another command to it. So `webpack -d -w && nodemon index.js` never gets to the `nodemon` part.

A solution to the above is to chain them using only `&`, which I guess you are doing, but in this way they both start at the same time. Hence, if you make your setup independent (webpack doesn't interfere with nodemon starting script) you can list them like so.

If for whatever reasons you can't do this or don't want to, your only option is with 2 separate scripts that you launch manually one after the other.

Comment: Thanks for the help i think i worked it around by creating this script: "dev" : "npm start & npm run dev" where npm start is a script creating an empty server.js file and npm run dev beeing the webpack -w nodemon. This is only used in developement mode

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would just use [nodemon-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon-webpack-plugin):

> Uses Nodemon to watch and restart your module's output file, but only
>   when webpack is in watch mode (ie, --watch).
>
> Saves the need for installing, configuring and running Nodemon as a
>   seperate process.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make nodemon wait for the build if you are running everything in parallel. This gets even more complicated if you are watching for changes - in this case the nodemon will never be called.

What you have to do is **check if the build is there and apply a if else logic to the build scrip** before running the app by nodemon. You can use path-exists package for this checking. It will provide standard bash behaviour:

```
path-exists ./mypath && 'script for existing path' || 'script for non existing path'
```

If you do not want to use path-exists and you use linux like system you can replace it with this command:

```
[ -d './server.js' ]
```

EXAMPLE:

```
"run_nodemon": "path-exists ./server.js && yarn run nodemon_watch || yarn run build_server && yarn run nodemon_watch",
"build_server": "HERE YOU BUILD THE ./server.js BEFOR CALLING THE run_nodemon",
"nodemon_watch": "nodemon ./server.js --watch ./src/server"
```

This condition && success || failure is typical way of handling bash scripts in linux-like environments.

```
[ TEST_COMMAND ] && (
  THEN_EXPRESSIONS
) || (
  ELSE_EXPRESSIONS
)
```

I use this in a more complicated environment where we have dev, site, app and server combined into single monorepo where some of the scripts have to run in parallel with watch flags in webpack that would cause the hanging up of the script mentioned in one of the answers. Please use this as a reference:

```
"app": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --config webpack/webpack.app.dev.js",
"prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/webpack.app.prod.js",
"prod:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack watch --config webpack/webpack.app.prod.js",
"site": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/webpack.site.prod.js",
"site:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack watch --config webpack/webpack.site.prod.js",
"server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/webpack.server.prod.js",
"server:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack watch --config webpack/webpack.server.prod.js",
"front": "npm-run-all --parallel site prod",
"front:watch": "npm-run-all --parallel site:watch prod:watch",
"web": "npm-run-all --parallel site prod server",
"web:watch": "npm-run-all --parallel site:watch prod:watch server:watch",
"listen": "nodemon ./dist/server/server.js",
"listen:watch": "nodemon ./dist/server/server.js --watch ./dist/server",
"deploy": "yarn run web && yarn run listen",
"dev": "path-exists ./dist/server/ && npm-run-all --parallel web:watch listen:watch || yarn run web && npm-run-all --parallel web:watch listen:watch",
```

I hope this is helpful! :D